# How to properly setup a service that interacts with SignalR Hub

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I am trying to create a service to interact with a SignalR Hub, which I've called `NotificationHub`. I've marked where `Clients` is null using this method. Is this the correct way to setup dependency injection with the Hub such that it can used with a service?

Notification Hub

```
public interface INotificationHub
    {
        Task Send(Notification notification);
    }
```

```
public class NotificationHub : Hub, INotificationHub
    {
        public async Task Send(Notification notification)
        {
            //Clients is null here
            await Clients.All.SendAsync(notification.Type, notification);
        }
    }
```

Notification Service

```
public interface INotificationService
    {
        Task SendNotificationToAll(Notification notification);
    }
```

```
public class NotificationService : INotificationService
    {
        private readonly INotificationHub _hubContext;

        public NotificationService(INotificationHub hubContext)
        {
            _hubContext = hubContext;
        }

        public async Task SendNotificationToAll(Notification notification)
        {
            await _hubContext.Send(...);
        }
    }
```

Trying to call from a controller:

```
public class SomeController : Controller {

        private readonly INotificationService _notificationService;
        public SomeController (..., INotificationService notificationService)
        {            
            _notificationService = notificationService;
        }
        [HttpPost, Route("notification")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Notification()
        {
            
            _notificationService.SendNotificationToAll(notification1);
        }
        
}
```

Comment: [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) tutorial explains how to setup SignalR

Comment: That tutorial is the basics, I have SignalR setup. I need to have my SignalR Hub used from a service.

Comment: You will have to use a .Net client to connect to your Hub inside your NotificationService class. You cannot directly inject the hub instance in a client.

Comment: @Scott In that case, use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/dotnet-client?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: It not the correct way to implement this, that why you get `Clients is null here` in your `NotificationService`. I will share my sample for you, hope it can inspire you.

Comment: Hello Scott, Any updates? If you have any concern about this issue, please let me know. Tks~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let check the test result first, and usually we implement this requirement like below steps.

[image]

*Project Structure*

There is no INotificationHub in my sample project.

[image]

*NotificationHub.cs*

```
using SignalrSample.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

namespace SignalrSample
{
    public class NotificationHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task SendMessage(Notification notification)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveNotification", notification.Type, notification);
        }
    }
}
```

*INotificationService.cs*

```
using SignalrSample.Models;

namespace SignalrSample.IService
{
    public interface INotificationService
    {
        Task SendNotificationToAll(Notification notification);
    }
}
```

*NotificationService.cs*

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using SignalrSample.IService;
using SignalrSample.Models;

namespace SignalrSample.Service
{
    public class NotificationService : INotificationService
    {
        // We should use private readonly IHubContext<NotificationHub> _hubContext;, 
        // then we can find Clients
        private readonly IHubContext<NotificationHub> _hubContext;

        public NotificationService(IHubContext<NotificationHub> hubContext)
        {
            _hubContext = hubContext;
        }

        public async Task SendNotificationToAll(Notification notification)
        {
            await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveNotification", notification.Type, notification);
        }
    }
}
```

*Model - Notification.cs*

```
namespace SignalrSample.Models
{
    public class Notification
    {
        public string? Type { get; set; }
        public string? Message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

*Test method inside the HomeController*

```
[HttpPost, Route("notification")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Notification([FromBody] Notification notification)
{
    await _notificationService.SendNotificationToAll(notification);
    return Ok();
}
```

*Program.cs*

```
using SignalrSample.IService;
using SignalrSample.Service;

namespace SignalrSample
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            // Add services to the container.
            builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
            builder.Services.AddSignalR();
            builder.Services.AddTransient<INotificationService, NotificationService>();

            var app = builder.Build();

            ...

            app.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            app.MapHub<NotificationHub>("/notificationHub");

            app.Run();
        }
    }
}
```